# MS Excel (2003) Find value in col 2 based on the row with col 1 having a value of x

Tags: excel, lookup

Is it possible to do this in excel?  Say I have a table like this:

```
-------------------
| foo | 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------------
| Bar | 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------------
| Bat | 7 | 8 | 9 |
-------------------
```

And I want to get the value in column B based on the row that has value x in column A.  So if I gave it the value 'foo' it would return 1.  If I gave it the value 'Bar' it would give me 4 and if I gave it 'Bat' it would give me '7'.

I don't think VLOOKUP is appropriate for this since it only can tell me if 'foo' exists in column A.

A google search doesn't return anything of value for me.

Thanks

Comment: you are wrong with VLOOKUP. it is able to return value from column B too, like `=VLOOKUP("foo", A1:d3, 2, 0)` will give you `1` as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vlookup would indeed work for this.  Say your table is in cols A-D, and your lookup value is in E1, then this would return what you're looking for:

```
 =VLOOKUP(E1, A:D, 2, FALSE)
```

The 3rd parameter, `2`, is the offset column to return.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, a VLOOKUP should work, providing you won't have the a name in column A repeating.  (It is recommended that you have the table sorted for the values in your first (leftmost) column in ascending order, but I have not experienced troubles when it isn't.)

Try VLOOKUP(A1,A1:C4,2,FALSE).

The 1st part, A1 - you're telling it what name it's looking for (in this case "foo").

The 2nd part, A1:C4 - you're identifying the range to look for it in - you have to include Column 1 where you have the names, and that needs to be on the leftmost column of your range.

The 3rd part - in this case "2" - you're stating that you want the value in the second column of your range (A1:C4) returned from the row that matches the name you identified in your first value (in this case, "foo").

And finally, the last part, FALSE - this will only return the value in the second column of your identified range if there is an exact match of Column A.

When you run this, you will get a return of 1 (cell A2 in your table).  If you change the 3rd value to 4, you will get a return of 3 (cell A4 in your table).